# Error 7 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm converting a lot of code from VB.net to c# and here is another issue I think cropped up during the conversion.

```
if (sRow.Cells[1].Value == true)
    Worked = "X";
else if (sRow.Cells[2].Value == true)
    Vacation = "X";
else if (sRow.Cells[3].Value == true)
    Sick = "X";
else if (sRow.Cells[4].Value == true)
    Holiday = "X";
```

on each of the if / else / else if lines it gives me this error.  I'm sure I am missing something that will force me to do a head bonk...

> Error  7   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure that these values are of type `bool`?

If so, just explicitly cast:

```
if ((bool)sRow.Cells[1].Value)
{
    Worked = "X";
}
else if ((bool)sRow.Cells[2].Value)
{
    Vacation = "X";
}
else if (sRow.Cells[3].Value)
{
    Sick = "X";
}
else if ((bool)sRow.Cells[4].Value)
{
    Holiday = "X";
}
```

Comment: Why need to cast bool as bool?

Comment: @Andrew C# is strict with compile-time type checking. `if(object)` will not compile, it must be of type `bool`.

Comment: Thank you, just seems like if `object.property` is boolean, (`sRow.Cells[1].Value` in this case), then no error should occur or casting needed. Probably it is somehow an object even if it's been assigned boolean true or false.

Comment: @Andrew - It's a compile time check, not a runtime check. We happen to know that it will be a boolean when the application runs, but the compiler does not know this at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that this is a cell of a DataRow which value is of type `object`. You cannot compare an object with a bool with the `==` operator.

So you should use the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301394) extension of `DataRow`:

```
if(sRow.Field<bool>(1))
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of `if (x == true)` generally, but using `if ((bool)sRow.Cells[1].Value)` or `if (Convert.ToBoolean(sRow.Cells[1].Value))` seems pretty opaque in terms of cognitive load.

This is a functional alternative:

```
if (true.Equals(sRow.Cells[1].Value))
    Worked = "X";
else if (true.Equals(sRow.Cells[2].Value))
    Vacation = "X";
else if (true.Equals(sRow.Cells[3].Value))
    Sick = "X";
else if (true.Equals(sRow.Cells[4].Value))
    Holiday = "X";
```

*Edit*: Reversed the comparison to support null values.

There's obviously a boxing cost, but if the code isn't particularly iterative, it won't be noticeable.

Some people are also put off by Yoda conditions.

However, casting/converting fails for DBNull, while this approach works:

```
object x = DBNull.Value;
if (true.Equals(x)); // False
if (Convert.ToBoolean(x)); // InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
if ((bool)x); // InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Error 7 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

That error is telling you that:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

`Value` is of type `object`, so if you would like to compare them in that manner you will need to cast it.

So, make sure `Value`'s underlying type is actually a boolean and then... dump the explicit comparison with true or false.  It's debatable and stylistic, but seriously redundant and unnecessary.  Would you ever say *"if true equals true then..."?*  No, probably (hopefully) not.

Comment: The pedantry is misplaced; you can actually compare with something meaningful, like "true" or "yes" (if the cell does, in fact, contain a string), or 1 or 0 if it is a number. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/12807

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's not pedantry at all; comparing something which is already a boolean to a literal boolean in order to produce a boolean expression is redundant, in every sense of the word.  I fail to see how your following statement is in any way relevant when we're talking about booleans (which we are):  *"you can actually compare with something meaningful, like "true" or "yes" (if the cell does, in fact, contain a string), or 1 or 0 if it is a number."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I saw the link, though I'm not sure what you meant to prove by it.

Comment: The use of `== true` is discussed in excruciating detail there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Right, I'm still not sure what you meant to prove by it.  It *is* in fact redundant.

Comment: Well, you're clearly not the only one bothered by it. It doesn't really matter; it's a personal preference, and is probably optimized out by the compiler anyway.  If it's happening a lot, it means there's a naming problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sure, and I said as much.  It's obviously not a performance concern, I'm just not a fan of writing redundant code in general.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Already a boolean? Not in the case of null or DBNull.